Unit testing expressions with null coalescing using c# and Sonarcube
How do you do this at all, using c# and Sonar?
Given the code:
if (root?.hop1?.hop2.hop3?.value == "blah") // this condition is not covered as far as Sonar is concerned
{
  do(); // this line is covered as far as Sonar is concerned
} 

we can create an object to test do(), but how do you cover the actual condition? Supplying just a "happy" path leaves the condition uncovered, should we supply all the permutations constituting unhappy paths (which is a nightmare as this code is in the middle of another test) or how do you do it otherwise?

In order to hit all of those conditions, you need to test the cases where root is null, then root is not null but root.hop1 is null, then root.hop1 is not null but root.hop1.hop2.hop3 is null, and so on. Consider writing parameterised tests / helper methods you can call from your test to remove duplication in your test code

this call is right in the middle of another large method... it's just not feasible. why is it important to go through all the variations considering the else branch doesn't exist? if its not "blah" it doesn't matter what it is form the logical perspective, why demanding for the coverage for it?

I'm sure you are capable of properly parameterising that test so that you can pass in different values for root, while keeping everything else the same. Either way, we can't see any of that code, so it's not something we can help with unfortunately.

This is flagged up by branch coverage because that's what branch coverage does. It checks to see whether all branches have been taken. If you had written your code the old-school way, as if (root != null && root.hop1 != null && root.hop1.hop2.hop3 != null && root.hop1.hop2.hop3.value == "blah"), does that make it clearer? You'd expect code coverage to flag up that if statement if you hadn't hit all of the different combinations of inputs, because that's the entire point of branch coverage

I'm assuming this data is coming from a service, so just parameterize with a testcase and run through the same test with different values it?

@canton "I'm sure you are..." the values is received from another call so it can't be manipulated easily. Also it's large method which is already parametrized. have you guys wrote any code at all in the past or just answer the questions? lol.

@vladimir_1969_2 No need to be snarky. I've done this sort of thing many times. (Ironically, I'm on SO because I'm writing unit tests and I'm bored). Ultimately though, your question as it stands has been answered. If you have problems actually unit testing your method because of code that you haven't shared, I'm afraid there's not much we can do to help

Of course sorry. you must have dealt with the different code comparing to what I deal with lol. I'll tell you secret - not every call is back by the interface so if you have some interim call results it as easy to mock them as deriving a private key from the public one. Anyway thanks for sharing.

On a serious not I asked about the value delivered by such tests - and got no reply.

You asked how to cover the condition (answered). The value of branch coverage as a whole is to test whether your test has covered every applicable combination of inputs.  For example, your code snippet might have a bug, if root?.hop1?.hop2 could actually be null (you wrote root?.hop1?.hop2.hop3?.value, but maybe that's a typo and it should be root?.hop1?.hop2?.hop3?.value). In that case, the branch coverage would help pick it up. If branch coverage isn't useful for a particular line, you have various ways to suppress it

being? /I asked how to resolve the issue. Obv. the missing coverage adds no value what so ever.

See my first comment. If you have trouble actually doing that because your test code is complex, I'm afraid we can't help with that, as you haven't shared your test code. Or are you asking how Sonarqube suppression comments work?

It's not feasible buddy we both know what. in theory this might work but it will add a whole lot of complexity and clutter the code, in fact diminishing the value of null coalescing never mind the rest.

I'm not sure what you want me to say I'm afraid, buddy. If you don't think that covering every branch has value in this case, then... don't. We can't make that decision for you.

I wanted to say that it's has a know flow when testing null coalescing expressions, forcing people to do a lot of extra work while adding virtually zero value. That's it.

I pointed out where such coverage does have value in the general case, a couple of comments ago. If you want to say that it has no value to you in this case, go ahead, but I'm not sure how you want me to help you with that?

I hear you. Once again in a situation when N/C expression is get evaluated to a single value (simple assignment of if without else) it's completely unnecessary to demand for the early exit values. Think about it this way - when you test a simple if without "else" branch - would sonar demand for both true and false values for the expressions containing no "?" ? The answer is - NO. So why would it do this for N/C expressions?? The onus is on Sonar indeed and has got nothing to do with c#.

Sonar is applying a fairly simple algorithm, because you asked it to (by enabling that setting). Don't blame it :P

Simple but hm...? Can it be made to recognize such simple scenarios and lift the demand for the early exits, or it's just too simple for this? :)

What you can do is to define parameter for test method and provide it ClassData attribute with type of data generator, which would produce all combinations.
Considering such setup:
public class Innermost
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class Inner
{
    public Innermost Innermost { get; set; }
}
public class Outer
{
    public Inner Inner { get; set; }
}
public class Outermost
{
    public Outer Outer { get; set; }
}

public static class ClassUnderTest
{
    public static string? GetString(Outermost o)
    {
        if(o?.Outer?.Inner?.Innermost?.Value == "value")
        {
            return "value";
        }
        return "";
    }
}

You could define data generator in separate class:
public class TestDataGenerator : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var outerMost = new Outermost();
        yield return [outerMost];

        outerMost = new Outermost();
        outerMost.Outer = new Outer();
        yield return [outerMost];

        outerMost = new Outermost();
        outerMost.Outer = new Outer();
        outerMost.Outer.Inner = new Inner();
        yield return [outerMost];

        outerMost = new Outermost();
        outerMost.Outer = new Outer();
        outerMost.Outer.Inner = new Inner();
        outerMost.Outer.Inner.Innermost = new Innermost();
        yield return [outerMost];

        outerMost = new Outermost();
        outerMost.Outer = new Outer();
        outerMost.Outer.Inner = new Inner();
        outerMost.Outer.Inner.Innermost = new Innermost();
        outerMost.Outer.Inner.Innermost.Value = "random string";
        yield return [outerMost];
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

And then use it inside test:
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(TestDataGenerator))]
    public void Test1(Outermost outerMost)
    {
        var result = ClassUnderTest.GetString(outerMost);

        Assert.Equal("", result);
    }
}

This way all data generation will be separated in different class. There you could also leverage AutoFixture package to further simplify object creation in unit tests.

Thank Michal. The issue with N/C relates to multiple lines within the same method, so it wouldn't be practical to apply patterns like this as they will result in having many unneeded permutations just to test nothing.

@vladimir_1969_2 This is solution in case you needed something, that would not affect much unit test itself. But if you don't want to test all the permutations (which seems reasonable), then you have to accept that your coverage tool won't let that slip :)

That was my Q, maybe poorly formed - the issue must be pretty common, I can hardly imagine that people "parametrize" their tests for every occurrence of N/C usage tbh.

My answer is - in a situation when an expression containing "?" is evaluated to a value or checked with a standalone if branch it's completely unnecessary to demand for the values representing "early exits", it adds nothing but the hustle.
I'd suggest to refactor SUT code to use something like target.Evaluate<T>("hop1.hop2.hop3").
